# Do I need to edit MySQL ? or there is a WP plugin could do it?

Tags: mysql, plugins, wordpress

Is there any WP technique that could help me search inside all my posts for a certain expression, then add all these posts to a new category? Or assign a new author for all of them? For example, I have a WP website that contains more than 3000 posts, and we need to search for the word "Medical Operation" then moving all the posts that contain this expression to a new category named "Surgery". Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in WordPress itself*.

Open the posts page and use the search box and look for "Medical Operation". You will get a result of all the posts that contain that string. If there are more than 20 posts you might need to click on "Screen Options" in the top right have corner of the screen and change "20" to a higher number, so more can be seen on one page.

Once that is done, tick the box beside "Title" to select all the posts that were returned and above that box there is a drop down list, select the "Edit" option and then the "Apply" button beside it.

A new box will appear and there will be a heading in it called "Categories", tick the category that you want the posts to have and then click the "Update" button.*

*I have used this myself numerous times, but if you add the category "Surgery" and the posts already have a category set to "Blog Post" then after pressing update those posts will have "Blog Post" and "Surgery" as a category. I haven't been able to find a way to remove the original category.

Comment: Thanks a lot Howlin, Its first time to know that I could do that from my dashboard. Thanks a gain !